# Using NodeJS (and FS) to retrieve directory names along with the amount of contents of each directory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use NodeJS and FS to create a list with the names of all files in a directory along with their **.length**s. Is there anyway to do that easily?

If not, I can settle for a way to find out what directory is the biggest (contains the most files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this script several months ago, not sure if its optimal though;

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

let currentDir = process.argv[2] || __dirname

function filterDirectory (dirPath, type) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dirPath)
            .map(c => path.join(dirPath, c))
            .filter(c => fs.statSync(c)[type]())
}

function sortFoldersByFileCount (rootPath) {
  return filterDirectory(rootPath, 'isDirectory')
          .map(dirPath => ({
            directory: dirPath,
            files: filterDirectory(dirPath, 'isFile').length
          })).sort((a, b) => b.files - a.files)
}

const results = sortFoldersByFileCount(currentDir)
console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 4))
```